# Mozilla Firefox not correctly downloading certain file types from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, excel, firefox

I have a MySQL database where I store various file types. If the file extension is the standard three character (.doc, .xls, .pdf), then the content type is stored as application/msword, application/ms-excel, application/pdf, etc. If it's .docx or .xlsx, then the content type is application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.

Until recently, this has never been a problem, but within the past few weeks, it's become a problem in Firefox. Firefox will not download files of type application/vnd.openxlmformats-officedocument in their correct formats. Instead, it downloads the file without an extension and the user has to add it manually. Furthermore, if there are spaces in the filename, then Firefox only picks up the first word in it and that's how the file is saved.

Here is the code I use to upload files:

```
if($_FILES['Budget']['size'] > 0)
   {
    $fileName = $_FILES['Budget']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['Budget']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['Budget']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['Budget']['type'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));

    fclose($fp);

    $fileUp = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ptfs.upload (ProposalNo, name, size, type,  content) VALUES(:proposalno,:name,:size,:type,:content)");
    $fileData=array('proposalno'=>$proposalNo,'name'=>$fileName,'size'=>$fileSize,'type'=>$fileType,'content'=>$content);
    $fileUp->execute($fileData);
   }
```

And here is the code for presenting the file link to the user:

```
if(isset($_GET['ProposalNo']) && isset($_GET['UID']))
  {
   $fileget = $con->prepare("SELECT name, type, size, content FROM upload WHERE ProposalNo = :proposalno AND UID = :uid");
   $data = array('proposalno'=>$_GET['ProposalNo'],'uid'=>$_GET['UID']);
   $fileget->execute($data);
   list($name, $type, $size, $content) = $fileget->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
   header("Content-type: $type");
   header("Content-length: $size");
   echo $content;

   exit;
  }
```

This works fine in every browser except Firefox, and as I said, it's a recent problem.  My users started reporting it within the last couple of weeks. Can I modify either my code or my database to make sure that FF downloads these file types correctly again?

Comment: files with spaces in the names should be entered into the content header with quotes: `Content-.....; filename="file with spaces.txt"`

Comment: It's always best to catch the problem right away (*before file is uploaded and entered into DB*) and replace spaces with underscores, then let PHP do its thing afterwards. That's what I do and it never let me down since.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Furthermore, if there are spaces in the filename, then Firefox only picks up the first word in it and that's how the file is saved."*

---

It's always best to catch the problem right away (before the file is uploaded and entered into DB) and replace spaces with underscores, then let PHP do its thing afterwards.

Consider the following which is the logic I use for my uploaded files, which will transform:

`This is a line`

into:

`This_is_a_line`

```
<?php
$string = "This is a line";
$arr = explode(" ",$string);
$string = implode("_",$arr);
echo $string;
?>
```

This taken from my own experiences with the same issue that resolved it.

Comment: Well, this took care of the filename problem, but what about the problem with Firefox not recognizing the content type?

Comment: @Chris I'm not quite sure about that one. I have seen others using variables (similar method) for `Content-type);` similar to what you have `header("Content-type: $type");` and 95% of the time, ended up being what was pulled in from DB.

Comment: Yeah, and it's weird that it's only happening in Firefox. IE, Chrome, Safari, and Opera are all working fine.

Comment: @Chris Which as far as I can remember, was also the case. Which version of FF are you using? Plus, have you tried using `application/msword, application/ms-excel` for `.docx` and `.xlsx` files to see if the problem persists?

Comment: Your solution actually solved both problems. It would've helped if I had refreshed the page after dropping it in!

Comment: @Chris Funny you should say that. Just as I went to make myself a cup of coffee, thought of the very same thing! I'm glad to hear that everything worked out and was happy to have helped, *cheers.*